# Python turtle program dies with 'Exception in Tkinter callback' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Using Python: I am trying to make a game where the turtle must not retrace its steps (a bit like single player Tron), but I get 'Exception in Tkinter callback' when I try to run my program.
the error is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GURNHH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\GURNHH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\turtle.py", line 686, in eventfun
    fun()
  File "C:/Users/GURNHH/OneDrive - Rugby School/ICT/Python/bored.py", line 20, in k1
    t.forward(10)
  File "<string>", line 5, in forward
turtle.Terminator
```

and my program is:

```
import turtle as t
from turtle import *
setup(1200, 700)
Screen()
title("Turtle Keys")
showturtle()

turns = 0
badpos = []

def k1():

    if t.pos in badpos and badpos.index(t.pos) == turns:
        print("die")
        print(t.pos)
        t.color("red")
        t.bye()
    else:
        pass
    t.forward(10)
    badpos.append(t.pos)

def k2():
    t.left(90)

def k3():
    t.right(90)

t.onkey(k1, "Up")
t.onkey(k2, "Left")
t.onkey(k3, "Right")

listen()
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're calling `t.forward(10)` after you've shutdown the turtle window with `t.bye()`.  Below's my rework of your code to sort out various problems and get it to basically work:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def k1():
    turtle.forward(10)

    position = (int(turtle.xcor()), int(turtle.ycor()))

    if position in badpos:
        turtle.color("red")
        screen.bye()

    badpos.add(position)

def k2():
    turtle.left(90)

def k3():
    turtle.right(90)

turtle = Turtle(shape="turtle")

badpos = set()

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1200, 700)
screen.title("Turtle Keys")

screen.onkey(k1, "Up")
screen.onkey(k2, "Left")
screen.onkey(k3, "Right")

screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

I've dropped the `turns` logic as that seemed incomplete since the `turns` variable never changed its value.  You'll need to add back the intended logic, if you still need it.